# Named Query and Inheritance

Tags: c#, nhibernate, inheritance, named-query

I'm having some issues when running a named query on NHibernate. The class I'm setting as the return value is **Organization** - not abstract -, and I have a second class (which inherits from this one) called **FullOrganization**. I have a table per concrete class schema and everything else is working just fine, but I keep getting an exception when running the named query (which BTW doesn't provide any details).

The mapping is close to the following:

```
<hibernate-mapping 
xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
namespace="XXX" 
assembly="XXX" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2 ..\nhibernate-mapping.xsd" auto-import="false">
<class name="Organization" table="Organizations" lazy="false">
    <id name="Identity" column="Id">
        <generator class="identity"/>
    </id>

    <property name="Name" column="Name" />
    <many-to-one name="OrganizationType" column="OrganizationTypeId"/>
...
            <joined-subclass name="FullOrganization" table="FullOrganizations" lazy="false">
        <key column="OrganizationId"/>
                    ...
            </joined-subclass>
</class>
```

And the named query goes something like:

```
<sql-query name="OrganizationSearch" read-only="true" cacheable="false">
<return class="Organization" />
<![CDATA[
  SELECT *
  FROM Organizations o
  INNER JOIN OrganizationTypes ot ON o.OrganizationTypeId = ot.Id 
  LEFT JOIN FullOrganizations fo ON o.Id = fo.OrganizationId
  WHERE 
    // Several Filters Here
]]>
```

How should I map the query results? Please take into account that returned objects could be instances of Organization or FullOrganization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding the question correctly, do you have two methods for the search? i.e.

`SearchOrganisations` and `SearchFullOrganisations`

If answer is yes then I would remove the

`<return class="Organization" />`

and in code you can use the `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`

so one method

```
return Session
    .GetNamedQuery("OrganizationSearch")
    .SetString("Param1", param1)
    .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(Organization )))
    .List<Organization >();
```

and also

```
return Session
    .GetNamedQuery("OrganizationSearch")
    .SetString("Param1", param1)
    .SetResultTransformer(new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof(FullOrganization )))
    .List<FullOrganization >();
```

If you have one method then you can set a switch to apply the desired `SetResultTransformer`

Comment: Actually I was expecting I could use a single search method, that's why I'm doing a LEFT JOIN on the sql query, and the conditions on the WHERE part are all of the kind OR (fo.<Field> IS NOT NULL AND fo.<Field> LIKE :pattern). But now that you mention it, I might be wrong about that assumption as NHibernate should create Organization or FullOrganization instances depending only if the FullOrganization  fields are not NULL...

Comment: I didn't follow this exact implementation, but instead used a DTO for the result set. However, I'm marking the answer as accepted as it lead me to the resolution. Thanks!